# Why is it that I must make Bootstrap's jumbotron set to position:relative in order for a fixed element with a z-index of -1 to scroll under it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, positioning

I have a fixed element with a z-index of -1. I want this to scroll under another element (jumbotron) with z-index of 1. For the rows, it worked fine when I set the z-index of the body to 1, except for the jumbotron. Until I set the position to relative, the fixed element with a -1 z-index was still scrolling on top of it. Could anyone please give me some intuition behind this?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to post your html and css code so someone can help you, it depends on many factors such as the elements order in the markup.

Comment: If a position is static then you can't change the z-index if it's relative then you can, this is basic css.